# How to map entlib.config on a webservices webconfig with relative path?

Tags: c#, web-config, enterprise-library

it seems that if I don't give the correct path (i.e. c:\something\entlib.config) I get the following error when running the webservice:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file Entlib.config could not be found.
(...)

This is the Webconfig part that refers to the entlib file:

```
<enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource selectedSource="EntLibconfig" parentSource="">
<sources>
  <add name="EntLibconfig"
       type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
       filePath="Entlib.config" />
</sources>
</enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource>
```

I've tried several combinations already 
           filePath="Entlib.config" />
           filePath=".\Entlib.config" />
           filePath="~\Entlib.config" />
           filePath=".\Entlib.config" />
           filePath="~\Entlib.config" />

Comment: If you want you can just put the Entlib.config within your own app.config, then you don't have to worry about looking for the path. Are you happy to do this?

Comment: This would be a solution, but would not be good each time i would have to edit Entlib.config. Is there a way to map the relative path ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this was a [bug introduced in version 5](http://entlib.codeplex.com/workitem/26760).  It looks like it is fixed in [Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 Optional Update 1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6836).

Or you could extend `FileConfigurationSource` and override the `CreateSource` method (as in the bug report comments above).

Comment: I will try this solution and report back to you

Comment: When I try to install it says I already have the latest version, so probably this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Project setyp folder then you can add a custom Project Installer file, then after the install has completed you can find the entlib.config file because you know from the installer where the files were installed and then open the entlib.config and replace the current path with the installed path.

```
        private void serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        //Gets Installed Directory that user selected
        string installDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Context.Parameters["assemblypath"]);


        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(installDirectory + "\\NLog.config");
        File.Delete(installDirectory + NLOGFILE);
        StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(installDirectory + "\\NLog.config");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("LOGS"))
            {
                string logDir = line.Replace("LOGS", installDirectory + "\\LOGS");
                sw.WriteLine(logDir.Replace('\\', '/'));
            }
            else
            {
                sw.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
    }
```

I do something similar with Nlog.config.

Update

"The path can be a relative or absolute path." Please see [this link](http://www.pnpguidance.net/News/EnterpriseLibraryExternalConfigurationSourceApplicationBlockSettings.aspx) for further details.

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for something that didnt envolve tampering with the code. There must be an easier way I am sure..